# Make Programmatic login without username/password?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Greetings all
i am using the following method to make programmatic login for the user, but with his username & password, and it works fine:

```
public static void autoLogin(User user, HttpServletRequest request,
   AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

  GrantedAuthority[] grantedAuthorities = new GrantedAuthority[] { new GrantedAuthorityImpl(
    user.getAuthority()) };

  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
    user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
    grantedAuthorities);

  // generate session if one doesn't exist
  request.getSession();

  token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
  Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager
    .authenticate(token);

  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
  // setting role to the session
  request
    .getSession()
    .setAttribute(
      HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

 }
```

and i was wondering if it's possible to make programmatic login but without the username or the password authentication, just makes this user authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to do it by removing those lines

```
token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request)); 
Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager .authenticate(token);
```

Comment: If you removed those two lines, how did the following line compile?                                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own subclass of `Authentication`, implement an `AuthenticationProvider` that supports it and configure authentication manager to use this provider.

(Actually, you can simply put a custom `Authentication` that always returns `true` from `isAuthenticated()` into `SecurityContext`, but this approach bypasses `AuthenticationManager`, so, for example, `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` wouldn't be published).

Comment: managed to do it by removing those lines token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
  Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager
    .authenticate(token);