# Programmatically login from a link in spring security

Tags: spring-security

i am trying to automatically authorization without login in spring security. The user would be authorized by clicking a link in a website.

I have a class UserLoginService that called from spring-security xml file like this;

```
     <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userLoginService" >
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>   
        </authentication-provider> 
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userLoginService"
        class="tr.com.enlil.formdesigner.server.guvenlik.UserLoginService">

    </beans:bean>
```

UserLoginService class;

```
public class UserLoginService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InitServlet.class);

    @Autowired
    private IKullaniciBusinessManager iKullaniciBusinessManager;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        try {
            Kullanici kullanici = new Kullanici();
            kullanici.setKullaniciAdi(username);
            Kullanici kullaniciBusinessManager = iKullaniciBusinessManager.getirKullaniciAdinaGore(kullanici);
            User user = new User();
            if (kullaniciBusinessManager != null && kullaniciBusinessManager.getAktifmi()) {
                user.setUsername(kullaniciBusinessManager.getKullaniciAdi());
                user.setPassword(kullaniciBusinessManager.getSifre());
                user.setKullanici(kullaniciBusinessManager);
                List<String> yetkiListesi = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<GrantedAuthority> grandAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                //TODO yetkilerle alakalı birşey yapmak gerekebilir.
                for (String yetki : yetkiListesi) {
                    GrantedAuthorityImpl g = new GrantedAuthorityImpl(yetki);
                    grandAuthorities.add(g);
                }
                user.setAuthorities(grandAuthorities);
            }
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Kullanici alinirken hata olustu!!", e);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static void autoLogin(User user, HttpServletRequest request, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());

        // generate session if one doesn't exist
        request.getSession();

        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
        Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
        // setting role to the session
        request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

    }
}
```

I found autoLogin method from [Make Programmatic login without username/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125862/make-programmatic-login-without-username-password). But i dont know, from where can i call this method and will this code help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own implementation of AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.  The method getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) will have the request where you can get your credentials from.  You will need to return a subject if it is a valid user or null if it is not.  Your implementation of UserDetailsService will transform the subject to a UserDetails object.